# Importing Multiple .ICS files into Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, ics

Unfortunately we have over 4000 .ics files that we need to import into Outlook 2013. Each file is one event. What's the best way for doing this?

Comment: You realize that once imported 4000 calendars will slow Outlook down right?  Are you sure you want to do that?

Comment: ICS is just an event. You can import events into one calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the .ICS (or iCals) format is a textfile, I would merge all files into one .ICS file and import that one file.

Just open your .ics file and look at the layout. You can also read about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar

*The wikipedia article is too long to quote, so thats why I haven't done that.*

Comment: This is when installing cygwin and using cat *.ics > all_ics.txt is useful. Then rename all_ics.txt to all.ics to perform the event import.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work in Outlook 2010

Comment: Well - actually it works if you manually edit out all the interim BEGIN:VCALENDAR & END:VCALENDAR as per https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!msg/calendar/KJ_rH90hIDA/6JrHK7ho4_EJ

Answer (score 0):

**Drag and drop** was the option I found for the case where I had just enough .ics events to import manually through the general `file > import/export > iCalendar` process for each file, but not enough to justify writing the script to concatenate all the details of the files into one

You should be prompted with a window that lets you see/confirm the details then click Save to add to the calendar. A bonus is Outlook syncs with Teams -- which is where I needed the events to be seen.